# Selling an application without the source code

Tags: google-play, app-store

I received on offer to sell my application, but I am worried about sharing my source code.
Is there away for the buyer to distribute the app to the app stores without the source code?

If the app is written in react native? swift? android studio?

* I don't want legal information, only up-to-date technical from the developers here.

Thank you